# Radius of convergence $\cos^{2}x$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I have developed the the taylor series of $\cos^{2}x$.

$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot (2n+1)\cdot x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

$$\cos^{2}x=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Now I have to bring the series to a form of $\sum a_nx^n$

Can I used $t=2n\Rightarrow n=\frac{t}{2}$

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\frac{t}{2}=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\frac{t}{2}}\cdot x^{t}}{(t)!}$$

So $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{t}{2}}}{t!}$$

So $R=\lim_{t\to \infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|=\frac{(1)}{t!}\cdot\frac{(t+1)!}{1}=\lim_{t\to \infty} (t+1)=\infty$

Are the steps correct? can I say that beacuse $$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ had $R=\infty$ so does the new series?

Comment: In the third line, you need $(2x)^{2n}$ (you forgot the factor 2).

Comment: @orion thanks, so $a_{n}=\frac{(-4)^n}{2n+1}$ and then I need to use $R=lim_{t\to \infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$ test?

Comment: Yes. And the result is not surprising. You just stretched and shifted the series a little, so nothing dramatic can happen to the convergence.

Comment: Small technical thing about your derivation: Your $a_n$ is not entirely correct as we have $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{n!}$ when $n$ is even, but $a_n = 0$ when $n$ is odd. This means that “$a_{n+1} / a_n$” is not a well defined ratio. Instead compute $\text{n+1’th term} / \text{n’th term}$ and show that this goes to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$ \cos(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ \cos^2(x) = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2} = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n-1} x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\tag{2} $$
and both $\cos(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$ are entire functions, with radius of convergence $+\infty$.